# How do I check if the person getting kicked is the author or a bot?

Tags: discord.py

I have been working on this for quite some time and I still can't figure this out! I have been trying many different ways to check if member is not the author nor a bot!

```
@bot.command() #kick (verified works)
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members = True)
async def kick(ctx, member : discord.Member, *, reason = None):
    if member == ctx.author.bot:
        await ctx.send("Unfortunatly I cannot do that!")
        return
    else:
        await ctx.send('Kicked the member {}'.format(ctx.member.mention))
        await member.kick(reason = reason)
        await ctx.message.delete()
```

This is my kick command! Unfortunately it does not return anything if its the bot or author! And even just using it to kick someone does not work for some odd reason! Could someone help out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking if it's a bot is pretty simple and you nearly had it. To check if it's the same person you take the member and compare it to the author

```
if ctx.author.bot or member == ctx.author:  # If the author is a bot ctx.author.bot is True
    await ctx.send("Unfortunatly I cannot do that!")
    return
```